# CSS:Positioning divs

Tags: css, css-float

i try to position the elements like this
[image]

but i get this
[image]

the html is

```
<div class="letters">
 <p class="letter">A</p>
 <p class="glostitle"></p>
</div>
```

the css is

```
.letters {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 280px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please upload complete css/html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot achieve that without javascript.

The better I can get is this: http://jsfiddle.net/QeWz2/2/

I used `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top` to get that behaviour

**Update**

I think [Columnizer](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Columnizer) is the jQuery plugin you are looking for.